# Launching A Package(Application) From Another Application Activity on Button Click

Tags: java, android

i wan currently developing an app for android, but.. There is an activity of mine, in which the user shall click on a button and it would open the Android Terminal EMulator which would have been installed on the user device, but right now, i have an issue, my codes are not working.. check it out

ClockWorkModFlash.java

> package com.loadedgeek.myupgrade;
>
> import android.os.Bundle; import android.app.Activity; import
>   android.os.Handler; import android.content.Intent; import
>   android.widget.Button; import android.view.View;
>
> public class ClockWorkModFlash extends Activity {
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.clockworkmod_activate);
>
>     Button bClock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.FlashClockWork);
>     bClock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>     public void onClick(View v) {
>     Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
>     PackageManager managerclock = getPackageManager();
>     i = managerclock.getLaunchIntentForPackage(jackpal.androidterm);
>     i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
>     startActivity(i);
>
>     }
>
>     });
>
> }}
> ```

The Eclipse is not allowing me compile the app, as that is the last activity, it says Packagemanager and OnClickListner could not be resolved... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                    intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("application Package name /application launcher activity name"));
                    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: sorry sir, but i think this code will move to next activity, i want it to open another application installed on the phone outside my app

Answer (score 0):

```
PackageManager managerclock = getPackageManager();
Intent i = managerclock.getLaunchIntentForPackage(jackpal.androidterm);
i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("jackpal.androidterm");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
startActivity(intent);
```

by the way,your error "*Packagemanager and OnClickListner could not be resolved*", I guess that you can change the code from:

```
bClock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {…}
```

to:

```
bClock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {…}
```